# Две замены с помощью jquery в одном и том же тексте

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт замены текста на текст с тегом span

```js
$('.bm').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Мега-холодильник ', '<span>Мега-холодильник </span> '));
});
```

```css
.bm span {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bm">
<a>Мега-холодильник Bosch-DF100 </a>
</div>
```

Скрипт работает но требуется произвести еще одну замену в этом же тексте.
Подскажите как изменить этот скрипт чтобы в этом же тексте поменять обычные дефисы на неразрывные `&#8209;`. Замену дефисов нужно произвести только в оставшейся части текста (в теге span дефис замены не требует, но если тоже заменится на неразрывный нечего страшного). 
Надо чтобы в финале получилось:

```
<div class="bm"><a><span>Мега-холодильник</span> Bosch&#8209;DF100</a></div>
```

Как будет выглядеть рабочий скрипт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.bm').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Мега-холодильник ', '<span>Мега-холодильник </span> ').replace(/-/g, '&#8209;'));
});
```

чтобы Мега-холодильник остался нормальный дефис

```
$('.bm').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/-/g, '&#8209;').replace('Мега&#8209;холодильник ', '<span>Мега-холодильник </span> '));
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо оба варианта рабочие!

Comment: Подскажите, а как добавить исключение чтобы дефисы не менялись в ссылке, внутри атрибута  href <a> href="....bosch-df100" >..Bosch-DF100 </a> а то ссылки битые получаются

Comment: если у вас заменяемый текст всегда внутри ссылок, то самое простое решение: $('.bm') заменить на $('.bm a')

Comment: Да действительно это помогло, спасибо!